# Javascript Link on my Site that Pre-Fills Form Field on Another Site

Tags: javascript, forms

I don't have access to update the code of the destination URL. I've tried guessing the appropriate URL query string to punch it through. No joy, there.

There's only one visible form field over there (input id="url" name="long_convoluted_string"); with "http://" as the sample/placeholder text.

It seems to me that javascript might be able to replace the placeholder text on the destination page (or use it's id/name), with the URL of my source page?

Maybe there's another better way? I'd settle on a simple bookmarklet, if there's no other way.

**Hey @zero298:** 
The text id field is probably not dynamically generated. I was uncharacteristically through, and it seems to be "master_pageContent_SinglePageCheckComponent_TableView_TextInput" every time. Does that provide any insights?

***Addenda:*** It does appear that the destination server dynamically generates a *processID* within the the query string, once the form is submitted. Doesn't seem to matter much from my perspective, but to someone with skills and insight, it might...

Comment: Is it possible that the `name="long_convoluted_string"` is dynamically generated by the server meaning it doesn't matter whether you can guess it or not?  Or does that string stay the same?

Comment: Almost certainly you cannot do what you wish. The remote site would have to parse the URL query string and overwrite its placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a form from your site to the target url of the form on the destination url. However it may fail if there is [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) check.

Comment: Building the script as a bookmarklet which pre-fills form field type="text" (or id="url") with "history(-1)" should circumvent a CSRF check, yes? Or perhaps I don't fully get it? Nothing malicious going on, here, BTW.

Comment: Yes, a bookmarklet will pass a CSRF check since the use is posting the original form including any hidden fields.

Comment: Thanks, @papirtiger. My initial indicate that these days, bookmarklets clearly seem to be out of vogue. But figuring it out will help our internal processes a great deal, in this case. Any samples of something similar or recommended resources ?